# Printing Some other characters

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
class Test{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        char a[]=new char[4];       
        DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            a[i]=in.readChar();
        System.out.println("Characters are : ");
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            System.out.println(a[i]);
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
java Test
a
s
d
f
Characters are : 
愊
猊
搊
昊
```

Here i read the characters a,s,d and f..but it prints some other charcters..

Comment: readChar method is suitable for reading bytes written by the writeChar method of interface DataOutput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input char is manipulated with below logic :

```
(char)((a << 8) | (b & 0xff))
```

See [readChar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readChar%28%29) docs:

> **public char readChar() throws IOException**
>
> Reads an input char and returns the char value. A Unicode char is made up of two bytes. Let a be the first
> byte read and b be the second byte. The value returned is: (char)((a
> << 8) | (b & 0xff))
>
> This method is suitable for reading bytes
> written by the writeChar method of interface DataOutput.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is read characters, you have a better options of using `BufferedReader`

You can use `public static BufferedReader newBufferedReader(Path path, Charset cs)` of the `Files` class to obtain a `BufferedReader`. In addition to supporting character sets, it is also highly efficient as it buffers the data :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, this will work,

```
        char a[]=new char[4];      
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            a[i]=(char) in.next().charAt(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Characters are : ");
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
```

Problem with your code is:

while the input is given, byte format of the input is considered and then Unicode value of byte is stored to a, so you get special characters.

Did not know how to do with **DataInputStream** so did it with **Scanner**,

Hope this helps!